# Online multiplayer first person shooter

Tags: windows, game

I'm looking for a video game that meets these requirements:

- First person shooter
- Online multiplayer
- Cannot pay to win (meaning you cannot use any *real* money to pay for in-game upgrades where it could give you an advantage over other players)
- Compatible with a Windows 10 PC
- In active development (meaning that there are new updates to the game constantly or that there are constantly new versions released)
- A level up game where if there is a new version to the game, your rank (for lack of a better term) stays with you (For instance, if a new version comes out, you don't have to start over ranking up)

Some preferences (but not requirements) are,

- Gratis (I do not mind paying for a game, though, as long as it is not a monthly subscription)
- Team support (ability to work with other players to complete a mission)
- Somewhat popular (does not have only a few people online at a time)

Comment: Could you clarify your last point a bit, leveling up implies an RPG sort of system, like you level up and gain more health or something. Ranking up is just a way to classify people into skill groups. Which one are you wanting in the game?

Answer (score 2):

[Counter Strike Global Offensive](http://blog.counter-strike.net/) (CS:GO) should be what you are looking for.

- It is an FPS
- It has several multiplayer modes (the one I prefer is competitive, it is the only one that influences the personal rank and the only one which penalizes players for leaving a game part way through):

  - Classic Casual and Competitive: Counter-Strike's most played game mode, involving either a bomb scenario or a hostage scenario. At the start of each round, players can purchase weapons and gear with money earned from various actions, from assisting on kills to completing objectives. Regardless of mission type, a round ends when one team completes an objective, eliminates the other team, or lets the timer run out. If the timer runs out before one of these objectives are completed, the team that wins is the one whose objective was to prevent the other team from completing their objective.
  - Arms Race: a deathmatch-based mode where each player is rewarded for each kill with a new weapon. The first player to get a kill with the golden knife, the final weapon on the list, wins the game.
  - Demolition: a round-based mode that removes weapon and equipment purchasing, instead rewarding players who manage at least one kill by giving the next weapon in a predetermined set of weapons.
  - Deathmatch: a mode consisting of 10-minute matches. Players must gain the highest possible score by earning kills, a bonus score is awarded for using certain weapons at different times.
- It is not a pay to win game, you can buy some gun skins but these are purely aesthetic and do not influence your game performance
- The development is very active, Valve constantly releases updates
- By playing the competitive mode, you will be given a ranking league which is a way of grouping players by skill. It is kind of different from a pure level system because you can go up as well as down depending on your performance. The rank is linked to your account so you will never lose it.
- You need to buy it but there is no subscription. You can find it for a reasonable price on Steam (15$ regular price and $7.50 when it is on sale which is several times a year)
- It is THE team game, players generally communicate well and need to cooperate and plan together otherwise they will not win very easily.
- It is [currently the 2nd most played game on Steam with over half a million current players](http://steamcharts.com/)

I do really like this game because it is always challenging thanks to a good matchmaking system and a huge community of players always online. Furthermore, it is always updated with new content that really boosts its longevity.

What I don't like about ​the game it's the absence of a story mode and the immature players you can find in low ranked matches.

Comment: Yes this fits all except the gratis preference of the OP, and even then it's not that expensive, only $15 and goes on sale to $7.50 every 2 or 3 months (was 7.50 just last week). I highly recommend it as well.

Comment: thanks, @Aequitas, $7.50 is very cheap compared to its competitors

Comment: @Tom Yeah, even the full price is cheap compared to a lot of other FPS's. But make no mistake it's not an incomplete or "cheap" game. A lot of my friends and myself as well have thousands of hours into csgo, well worth the price. You can [see here](https://support.steampowered.com/kb_article.php?ref=2025-HCVM-4206#wishlist) on information on how to be notified when CS:GO goes on sale again.

Answer (score 0):

If you are ready to pay something like 40$, you may also enjoy ***Star Wars : Battlefront***, it is a bit expensive but with very good content, it need a good graphic card by the way. There is a big community and playing with your team is much appreciated.